# Dealing with different time precision between Data.Time and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, haskell, esqueleto

I have some database functions which I'm testing (to make sure my queries etc. work) -- in them, I'm de/serialising records (via Database.Esqueleto.Experimental) and these contain values of type `UTCTime` (and `Maybe UTCTime`, etc.).

The problem is that I get these sorts of errors in my tests:

```
1) Vulture.Database.EventRepository.addEvents correctly sets the event properties
       expected: 2023-05-06 21:52:13.441270819 UTC
        but got: 2023-05-06 21:52:13.441271 UTC
```

This is sort of annoying, but I don't know how to either manipulate `UTCTime` values to change the precision, or to change the way the equality works here.

Comment: Do you need to test timestamps at all? There are certainly cases where it matters, but there are a lot of cases where all you're doing is testing the database. Your tests should cover your code, not an external component.

Comment: Well, "Your tests should cover your code" I agree -- what I'm trying to have test coverage over is the translation of my domain entities into the data-storage so that when I get them back out again, I have the right properties in the right places. These timestamps are part of the domain data, they aren't created/updated timestamps, so yeah I would like to be able to test them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, `UTCTime` by itself has a pretty sparse api. Just about everything interesting involves going via `NominalDiffTime`. For this case, I think you're best served by getting the difference between the two times and then making sure it's below some epsilon. For this, the relevant time function is [`diffUTCTime`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.12.2/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:diffUTCTime), and the rest takes advantage of the extensive set of instances available for [`NominalDiffTime`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.12.2/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:NominalDiffTime). Thanks to the `Num` instance, we have `abs` available. Thanks to the `Num` and `Fractional` instances, we can use literals to create `NominalDiffTime` values. And of course there's `Ord` for comparisons...

```
let eps = 1e-5 in abs (diffUTCTime t1 t2) < eps
```

Feel free to adjust `eps` as desired. And of course, you might need to adjust the structure of the whole thing to get good diagnostics out of the test framework.

Remember this as the basic framework for working with `UTCTime` - those values are just points in time. The really interesting stuff involves working with `NominalDiffTime` values which represent intervals between `UTCTime` values. Those intervals have a much richer API for manipulating them then the points have.

Comment: Thanks. FWIW I defined an assertion for HSpec to capture this:

```shouldBeCloseTo :: HasCallStack => UTCTime -> UTCTime -> Expectation
```